# Controller POST action responds "Unauthorized"

Tags: scala, playframework

Total noobie question, I'm just getting started with the Play framework.

I added a action "add" to my controller and when I try to access it I get the following page with HTTP 403 status.

[image: Unauthorized]

Controller:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import play.api._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.mvc._

/**
 * This controller creates an `Action` to handle HTTP requests to the
 * application's home page.
 */
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject() extends Controller {

  val userForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "todo" -> text
    )(TodoData.apply)(TodoData.unapply)
  )

  /**
   * Create an Action to render an HTML page.
   *
   * The configuration in the `routes` file means that this method
   * will be called when the application receives a `GET` request with
   * a path of `/`.
   */
  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

  def add = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
}
case class TodoData(todo: String)
```

Routes

```
# An example controller showing a sample home page
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
POST    /add                        controllers.HomeController.add

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

index.scala.html

```
@()

@main("Todo App") {
  <h1>Welcome to the Todo app</h1>
    <form action="/add" method="post">
        <label for="todo">TODO:</label>
        <input type="text" name="todo" id="todo">

        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours of digging around I managed to solve this myself. A case of RTFM.

There seems to be some magic Play does relating to POST requests and CSRF tokens. I was missing the CSRF token.

I changed the form a Play form:

index.scala.html

```
@(form: Form[TodoData])(implicit request: RequestHeader, messages: Messages)

@main("Todo App") {
  <h1>Welcome to the Todo app</h1>
    @helper.form(action = routes.HomeController.add()) {
        @helper.CSRF.formField
        @helper.inputText(form("todo"))
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.i18n._

/**
 * This controller creates an `Action` to handle HTTP requests to the
 * application's home page.
 */
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  val todoForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "todo" -> text
    )(TodoData.apply)(TodoData.unapply)
  )

  /**
   * Create an Action to render an HTML page.
   *
   * The configuration in the `routes` file means that this method
   * will be called when the application receives a `GET` request with
   * a path of `/`.
   */
  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index(todoForm))
  }

  def add = Action { implicit request =>
    val errorFunction = { formWithErrors: Form[TodoData] =>
      // This is the bad case, where the form had validation errors.
      // Let's show the user the form again, with the errors highlighted.
      // Note how we pass the form with errors to the template.
      BadRequest(views.html.index(formWithErrors))
    }

    val successFunction = { data: TodoData =>
      // This is the good case, where the form was successfully parsed as a Data.

      Redirect(routes.HomeController.index()).flashing("info" -> "Todo task added!")
    }

    val formValidationResult = todoForm.bindFromRequest
    formValidationResult.fold(errorFunction, successFunction)
  }
}

case class TodoData(todo: String)
```